# Can I store data from Google Maps API for personal, educational use? [2021]

Tags: legal-terms, terms-of-service, google

On the one hand, in previous questions, people write that you cannot (but I am not sure what use they are talking about), and on the other hand, Google itself 'proposes' to store API data in its tutorials https://developers.google.com/maps/solutions/store-locator.

I'm talking about storing data in order not to make the same requests to api over and over again for personal, educational use

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by "store data from the Google Maps API". The two Sore Locator examples at the link you give both assume that a user has an independent source of location data, and show hoe to make calls to teh Google Maps API to display that data as part of a web site. They don't seem to involve storing any data **from** Google Maps. Can you please give additional detail as to teh desired use case?

Comment: @DavidSiegel I'm talking about storing data in order not to make the same requests to api over and over again for personal, educational use

Comment: It sounds like you are talking about caching.  From [this answer](https://law.stackexchange.com/a/3589/24401) "That local browser caching is fair use is supported by a recent decision holding that Google's Click for Enhanced Coverage Linking Searches own cache constitutes fair use."

Comment: Ok, thank you. What about storing data in database?

Answer (score 1):

### Probably not

The [Google Maps/Google Earth Additional Terms of Service](https://www.google.com/help/terms_maps/?hl=en_US) section 2 b reads:

> you may not (or allow those acting on your behalf to): ...
> copy the content (unless you are otherwise permitted to do so by the Using Google Maps, Google Earth, and Street View permissions page or applicable intellectual property law, including "fair use");

and the [Google Maps Platform Terms of Service](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/terms/) section 3.2.3 reads:

> (b) No Caching. Customer will not cache Google Maps Content except as expressly permitted under the Maps Service Specific Terms.
>
> ...
>
> (f) No Circumventing Fees. Customer will not circumvent the applicable Fees.

However you are specifically allowed to "create KML files and map layers;" if that will satisfy your needs.

I don't find anything under the "Maps Service Specific Terms" that seems to explicitly allow the sort of storage you describe. So unless it is covered by fair use, or a similar exception to copyright, it would not be permitted. Fair use analysis requites more information about the specific use than is contained in the question, so i cannot asses that. Some countries have an exception to copyright for "personal use" but it is generally limited in some way. Without knowing what country the use would be in, and probably knowing more details about the use, That cannot be reliably analyzed either.